# StormSubmitter() executing Topology that is reading data from a rabbitmq spout at runtime

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am using a storm spout which is reading from a RabbitMQ queue. I am submitting the Storm topology (using StormSubmitter) to the cluster from the command prompt. So while running the topology, it should wait for the spout to read data off the queue, but its not doing.

Is it because the topology cannot read data at runtime?

I am running the topology as:
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout( "rabbitmqspout", new RabbitmqSpout() );
        builder.setBolt( "rabbitmqbolt", new RabbitmqBolt() )
        .shuffleGrouping("rabbitmqspout");
        Config conf = new Config();

```
    conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKERS, 4);
    conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_DEBUG, true);

    try {
        System.out.println("TOPOLOGY submitted");
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("rabbittest3", conf, builder.createTopology());
    }
```

The spout is reading from the rabbitmq queue as:

```
public void nextTuple() 
    {
    try
    {
    consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);            
        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);

        while(true){          
            QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();               
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody()); 
            collector.emit(new Values(new String(message)));      
              }   
    }
```

Comment: A Storm topology can of course read in data at runtime via a spout. You should provide more detail of what you have tried because it is likely to help us help you.

Comment: Can you create a connection to Rabbit without storm? What about `prefetch count` is it big enough?